# Исключение System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#

Почему вылетает это исключение в следующем коде

```
foreach (HtmlElement ell in inputEl)
        {                        
            if (ell.GetAttribute("value") == " sell ")//в этой строке кода вылетает исключение
            {
                //
            }
        }
Дополнительные сведения: Отказано в доступе. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Почитал про это исключение, вроде как оно вылетает, когда недостаточно прав к доступу. Но я работаю просто с обычным сайтом, его html разметкой.
Да и еще заметил одну вещь, что один проход отрабатывает, на 2ом вылетает исключение, закрываешь приложение, запускаешь заново, снова 1 раз отрабатывает на 2ой проход по циклу это исключение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам, исключение вылетает тогда, когда пытаешься получить\установить значение атрибута у элемента, который не имеет атрибутов.